# Python CSV Writes ;;;;;; to every line

Tags: python, csv

I stored data on a CSV file with Python. Now I need to read it with Python but there are some issues with it. There is a

> ";;;;;;"

statement on the finish of every line.

[image: There is a problem for me.]

Here is the code that I used for writing data to CSV :

```
file = open("products.csv", "a")
writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=",", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
writer.writerow(data)
```

And I am trying to read that with that code :

```
with open("products.csv", "r", newline="") as in_file, open("3.csv", "w", newline='') as to_file:
reader = csv.reader(in_file, delimiter="," ,doublequote=True)
for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

Of course, I am not reading it for just printing I need to remove duplicated lines and make it a readable CSV.

I've tried this to fetch strings and edit them and it's worked for other fields except for semicolons. I cant understand why I cant edit those semicolons.

```
    for row in reader:
    try:
        print(row)
        rowList = row[0].split(",")
        for index, field in enumerate(rowList):
            if '"' in field:
                field = field.replace('"', "")
            elif ";;;;;;" in rowList[index]:
                field = field.replace(";;;;;;", "")
            rowList[index] = field
        print(rowList)
```

Here is the output of the code above :

> ['Product Name', 'Product Description', 'SKU', 'Regular Price', 'Sale Price', 'Images;;;;;;']

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please include in your code the part where you assign something to `data`, so that we know what your data looks like, and we can have any hopes of reproducing your problem. Also, the lines you showed with ";;;;;;", is that a print() or in the file ?

Comment: change that `elif` to just `if`

Comment: Thanks man I've just realized it.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I used 'elif' on there. I changed it and it solved. Thanks for the help. But I still don't know why it added that semicolon to there.